LWT write shows as SERIAL CL
Using DataStax Java driver version 4.17.0 against Cassandra version 4.1.4, a LOCAL_QUORUM lightweight-transaction write to the same DC as a single-DC keyspace shows a Write-SERIAL rather than a Write-LOCAL_SERIAL statistic.  Is this expected behavior?
I haven't dug into whether the LWT is accessing remote DCs; this would be undesirable behavior.  Should it?

The serial consistencies SERIAL and LOCAL_SERIAL can only be used for setting the CL on the reads in the read-before-write for lightweight transactions (LWT). The serial consistencies cannot be used for LWT writes.
You didn't specify which "statistic" you were referring to so I can't say if it's incorrect or not. Cheers!

LOCAL_QUORUM is a consistency level that is only used by non LWT queries. The consistency level for non LWT queries is completely separate to the consistency level for LWT queries.
When you set local_quorum, all your regular queries will use local_quorum, but the LWT will use the default serial consistency which happens to be SERIAL if nothing is specified.
It will only do a LOCAL_SERIAL write if you set the consistency to LOCAL_SERIAL explicitly.  -> statement.setSerialConsistencyLevel(....)

I had tried using LOCAL_SERIAL, but I against a Cassandra 4.1.3 test container I got:
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: LOCAL_SERIAL is not supported as conditional update commit consistency. Use ANY if you mean "make sure it is accepted but I don't care how many replicas commit it for non-SERIAL reads"
Note that this was using a Mapper, with @StatementAttributes(consistencyLevel = "LOCAL_SERIAL") and a @Query("INSERT ...")

@JayK the serial CLs SERIAL and LOCAL_SERIAL only apply to the read phase of the read-before-write for LWTs. You cannot use serial CLs for writes. Cheers!
